# How to check if user has permission to edit content using the eZ Platform Public API in PHP?

Tags: ezplatform

[eZ Platform](http://ezplatform.com) is a Full Stack Symfony based Content Management System (CMS). It adds a content repository and other features that allow users to create content. This is controlled by [a sophisticated permissions system](http://doc.ez.no/display/DEVELOPER/Repository#Repository-Permissions) that allows finegrained control.

Normally these permissions are exposed through the user interface so that users can either perform certain functions or not. But how do I achieve this in my custom code, in Controllers or [Console Commands](https://symfony.com/doc/current/console.html)?

Answer (score 2):

Developers use standard services to interact with the repository. There are plenty of good examples of this in the [CookBookBundle](https://github.com/ezsystems/CookbookBundle/tree/master/Command). One thing that is not covered by the examples in the bundle is how to check if a user has permission to do a certain function.

You can do this easily by using the [PermissionResolver](https://github.com/ezsystems/ezpublish-kernel/blob/6.10/eZ/Publish/API/Repository/PermissionResolver.php) from the repository, for example:

```
$content = $contentService->loadContent(52);
$canEdit = $permissionResolver->canUser('content','edit',$content);

if($canEdit){
   echo "Logged in user can edit object " . $content->getName();
} else {
   echo "Logged in user can't edit object " . $content->getName();
}
```

This naturally applies to any commands and functionalities in the repository. For example, the content module has functionalities such as create, edit and remove.

Comment: Fantastic Point!